# Why is my multi-threaded program not terminating properly?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've written a multithreaded program that (I think) works as it should, but it doesn't seem to be terminating correctly. Most of the time it seems to run and provide no error (but not terminating with a return value) but every now and then it fails to print all loops and gives a runtime error. I'm very new to multithreading but more or less followed [this guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm)

What am I missing here? I assume it is some sort of catch to terminate the threads, but as far as I can tell I have that covered with pthread_exit. Please take a look and let me know if anything stands out to you. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct threadData {
    int     thread_id;
    int*    tArray;
    int     tArraySize;
    int     tQuery;
};

//this is included because for whatever reason the std::to_string fxn is not recognized by my compiler
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T value)
{
      //create an output string stream
      std::ostringstream os ;

      //throw the value into the string stream
      os << value ;

      //convert the string stream into a string and return
      return os.str() ;
}

//Counts the number of times the query is in the array
int countInstance(int* array, int arraySize, int query)
{
    int numInstance = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
    {
        if (array[i] == query) 
            numInstance += 1;
    }

    return numInstance;
}

void *threadFunction(void *threadArg)
{
    struct threadData *thisThread;

    thisThread = (struct threadData *) threadArg;

    //Originally wanted to use this to print each string, but it seemed to have issues printing correctly due to simultaneous threads
    /*cout << "Query: "         << thisThread->tQuery
         << "\tCount:  "    << countInstance(thisThread->tArray, thisThread->tArraySize, thisThread->tQuery) 
         << "\tThreadID: "  << thisThread->thread_id << endl;*/

    //Decided to create a concatenated string of the desired phrase instead.
    string queryString = to_string(thisThread->tQuery);
    string instanceString = to_string(countInstance(thisThread->tArray, thisThread->tArraySize, thisThread->tQuery));
    string idString = to_string(thisThread->thread_id);
    string outputString = "Query: " + queryString + "\tCount:  " + instanceString + "\tThreadID: " + idString + "\n";

    cout << outputString;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{   
    int arraySize = 1000;
    int numArray[arraySize];

    srand(time(NULL));

    //Populate array with random values ranged [0, 100]
    for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 
    {
        numArray[i] = (rand() % 101);
    }

    vector<int> numList;

    numList.push_back(1);
    numList.push_back(3);
    numList.push_back(5);
    numList.push_back(7);

    pthread_t threads[numList.size()];
    struct threadData data[numList.size()];
    int rc;

    for (int i = 0; i < numList.size(); i++)
        {
            data[i].tArray = numArray;
            data[i].tArraySize = arraySize;
            data[i].thread_id = i;
            data[i].tQuery = numList[i];
            rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadFunction, (void *)&data[i]);
            if (rc) 
                exit(-1);
        }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The *threadArg* pointer you pass to the threadFunction() is junk.  It is the local variable of a function that *might* no longer be running by the time the thread gets going.  Find a more permanent place to store the data.  Typical fire-and-forget threading bug btw.

Comment: @HansPassant, what would be a recommended solution here? Should I not be housing the data in that struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `pthread_exit(NULL)` you should put a loop of `join` calls to wait for the threads to complete:

```
for (int i=0; i<numlist.size(); i++) {
    void *rv;
    pthread_join(threads[i], &rv);
}
```

`pthread_exit` is used in a thread that is different from the main thread to abort it before its natural termination.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Do you know what the practical difference is in running this inside the original loop vs running it after? I noticed that when run after as a standalone loop the threads finished mostly in order but not necessarily always. However, when I inserted this at the end of the existing loop it seems to print the threads in the order they were created.

Comment: The `join` operation means "wait for the thread to finish". If you put the `join` inside the loop then you program is not really multithread at all (the main thread will spawn a new thread but then immediately will stop waiting for it to finish before starting next one). If you start all the threads first and then wait for all of them later then they will run in parallel. To see the parallelism of course the job needs to be long enough and to see a speed increase you need multithread hardware too: on a single core CPU multithread algorithms will just take longer.